# Is the GDAL-2.2.1.win32-py2.7.msi python binding compatible with gdal-202-1500-core and python 2.7.8 on Windows7?

Tags: gdal, installation

I am installing GDAL and cannot get python to load the module GDAL. After deinstalling and reinstalling I noticed that the names of the win32 files for the python bindings and gdal core are slightly different - gdal2.2.1 for the bindings and gdal-202 for the core. Is the 2.2.1 binding compatible with the 202 core?

My python installation comes from ArcGIS 10.3. Do I have to do anything else to configure the python bindings?

Comment: If the installers come from [GISInternals](http://www.gisinternals.com/) they should be compatible. I'm currently using _gdal-202-1600-x64-*.msi_ and _GDAL-2.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.msi_ succesfully on Windows 7 64bit.